# Segurança, quais ameaças além de um SQL Injection eu tenho de me preocupar com um campo de pesquisa?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, segurança, algoritmo-de-busca, sql-injection

Estou me aprofundando em programação web(com php) e estou com essa dúvida, já vi até algumas coisas parecidas em alguns lugares, mas indo direto ao ponto queria me falassem quais são as principais ameaças a segurança e suas soluções(em php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O SQL Injection, citado, seria o mais grave na perspectiva de integridade dos dados, caso exista tal erro poderia permitir editar, apagar e ler informações de maneira indevida.

Entretanto, existe também o [Blind SQL Injection](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/blind-sql-injection/), que ao contrário do primeiro apenas "pergunta" se algo existe ou não, assim permitirá descobrir outros conteúdos, o que pode ser tão perigoso quanto.

Mas existem outros lados além de apenas apagar seus dados.
Isso depende do que VOCÊ considera a palavra "Segurança", ou seja, **o que irei listar aqui pode (ou não) ser um problema de segurança.**

## CSRF

### Terceiros usando/coletando seus dados:

Dados de pesquisas podem ser extremamente detalhados. Isso pode permitir que outras pessoas possuam acesso as informações das pesquisas, inclusive podendo monitora-las se não houver algum limite.

Para demonstração irei usar o site da *saraiva.com.br*.

Sua API de pesquisa é essa:

```
http://busca.saraiva.com.br/autocomplete?q={PESQUISA (ENCODE HTML)}&apikey=saraiva-v5
```

> Esse link foi obtido através de monitoramento de trafego de rede, não é documentada ou publicamente documentada!

**Onde está o erro?**

Você pode fazer quantas requisições quiser, mesmo que nem acesse o site, não há monitoramento de IP, cookies ou sessões. Totalmente aberto e exposto para todos.

Por isso posso monitorar um livro desejado, como o Revolta de Atlas, em:

```
http://busca.saraiva.com.br/autocomplete?q=a%20revolta%20atlas&apikey=saraiva-v5
```

Isso retorna, HOJE, isso:

```
{"history": [], "products": [{"url": "//busca.saraiva.com.br/click?apikey=saraiva-v5&search_id=4322cd5c-5a89-4ee8-84cc-0dd8b501e647&pid=3093154&page=1&prodIdx=0&q=a+revolta+atlas&feature=autocomplete", "price": "71,90", "type": "product", "name": "A Revolta de Atlas - 03 Volumes", "image": "//dnsdprunamxb9.cloudfront.net/54x54/http%3A%2F%2Fimages.livrariasaraiva.com.br%2Fimagem%2Fimagem.dll%3FA%3D100%26PIM_Id%3D%26L%3D-1%26pro_id%3D3093154"}, {"url": "//busca.saraiva.com.br/click?apikey=saraiva-v5&search_id=4322cd5c-5a89-4ee8-84cc-0dd8b501e647&pid=4294739&page=1&prodIdx=1&q=a+revolta+atlas&feature=autocomplete", "price": "37,99", "type": "product", "name": "A revolta de Atlas", "image": "//dnsdprunamxb9.cloudfront.net/54x54/http%3A%2F%2Fimages.livrariasaraiva.com.br%2Fimagem%2Fimagem.dll%3FA%3D100%26PIM_Id%3D%26L%3D-1%26pro_id%3D4294739"}], "queries": []}
```

Por isso posso pegar o "price", para monitorar o preço desse livro e ser alertado se abaixar, por exemplo.

**Exemplo bobo, e que ninguém se preocupe com isso.**

**Agora vamos ao inverso?**

Exemplo a loja *kinguin.net*:

Sua API de pesquisa é essa:

```
http://www.kinguin.net/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/?q={PESQUISA}
```

> Esse link foi obtido através de monitoramento de trafego de rede, não é documentada ou publicamente documentada!

Entretanto isso possui várias limitações e que dificultam o seu uso.

Se buscar por "Siege" em referencia ao jogo "Rainbow Six Siege", em:

```
http://www.kinguin.net/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/?q=siege
```

Você deveria obter o resultado:

```
<ul class="ajax-result-list">
                <li class="ajax-result-item"><img src="http://cdn.kinguin.net/media/catalog/category/cache/1/image/95x66/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/rainbow_1.jpg" alt="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege Uplay CD Key" title="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege Uplay CD Key" width="95" height="66" />
            <span class="ajax-result"><a href="http://www.kinguin.net/category/22529/tom-clancy-s-rainbow-six-siege-uplay-cd-key/">Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege Uplay CD Key</a></span>
            <span><span class="price " data-no-tax-price="120.76">R$120<span class="super">.76</span></span></span></li>
                <li class="ajax-result-item"><img src="http://cdn.kinguin.net/media/catalog/category/cache/1/image/95x66/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/rainbow-six-siege_1.jpg" alt="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege Season Pass Uplay CD Key" title="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege Season Pass Uplay CD Key" width="95" height="66" />
            <span class="ajax-result"><a href="http://www.kinguin.net/category/22307/tom-clancy-s-rainbow-six-siege-season-pass-uplay-cd-key/">Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege Season Pass Uplay CD Key</a></span>
            <span><span class="price " data-no-tax-price="87.78">R$87<span class="super">.78</span></span></span></li>
                <li class="ajax-result-item"><img src="http://cdn.kinguin.net/media/catalog/category/cache/1/image/95x66/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/header_2298_4.jpg" alt="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege TR Uplay CD Key" title="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege TR Uplay CD Key" width="95" height="66" />
            <span class="ajax-result"><a href="http://www.kinguin.net/category/23140/tom-clancy-s-rainbow-six-siege-tr-uplay-cd-key/">Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege TR Uplay CD Key</a></span>
            <span><span class="price " data-no-tax-price="62.66">R$62<span class="super">.66</span></span></span></li>
                <li class="ajax-result-item"><img src="http://cdn.kinguin.net/media/catalog/category/cache/1/image/95x66/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/header_2298.jpg" alt="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege + Exclusive Gold Weapons Skin Pack Uplay CD Key" title="Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege + Exclusive Gold Weapons Skin Pack Uplay CD Key" width="95" height="66" />
            <span class="ajax-result"><a href="http://www.kinguin.net/category/22630/tom-clancy-s-rainbow-six-siege-uplay-cd-key/">Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege + Exclusive Gold Weapons Skin Pack Uplay CD Key</a></span>
            <span><span class="price " data-no-tax-price="125.36">R$125<span class="super">.36</span></span></span></li>
                <li class="ajax-result-item"><img src="http://cdn.kinguin.net/media/catalog/category/cache/1/image/95x66/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/header_292x136_496.jpg" alt="Hero Siege Steam Gift" title="Hero Siege Steam Gift" width="95" height="66" />
            <span class="ajax-result"><a href="http://www.kinguin.net/category/10152/hero-siege-steam-gift/">Hero Siege Steam Gift</a></span>
            <span><span class="price " data-no-tax-price="8.95">R$8<span class="super">.95</span></span></span></li>
                <li id="show-more-search"  class="show-more"><span class="show-more-result">SHOW MORE</span></li>
</ul>
```

Agora experimente acessar tal URL da API. Provavelmente irá obter uma página sem nenhuma informação. Mas acredite, essa é o URL, porém ele é minimamente protegido, não tão fácil quanto o do site anterior. :)

Além disso algumas APIs podem expor dados não listados ao usuário, por exemplo, um inicio de uma promoção, um código promocional, valores em outras moedas em outros países. Por isso tenha bom-senso no que informa em suas pesquisas e limite o acesso para usuários que realmente estão no site, por sessão, cookies, IPs e até um limite de tentativas. Agora, em alguns casos fazer isso será exagero, portanto DEPENDE DE CADA SITUAÇÃO!

### Mesmo problema, outros exemplos:

Imagine que sua busca também possua traços de últimas buscas feitas pelo usuário, problemas com CSRF permite que outro site obtenha as informações, assim como o caso anterior.

Caso permita que outros sites se conectem ou autorize o JSONP e não valide corretamente os dados poderá expor as preferencias/recomendações de um usuário, uma vez que tais filtros de pesquisas terão uma ordem baseada no visitante.

Um outro caso, imagine que em uma rede social os usuários possam saber que lhe buscou e visualizou o perfil. Apenas focando em quem lhe buscou, poderia criar algo do tipo:

```
<img src="meusite.com/buscar?amigo=Inkeliz">
```

Isso iria fazer com que eu (Inkeliz) recebesse uma notificação ao carregar tal conteúdo, por exemplo. Portanto se eu tiver um site e adicionar tal código seria possível descobrir a conta em tal rede social de cada visitante do site.

Uma saída nesse caso seria acrescentar um código "aleatório".

Por exemplo:

```
<?php $_SESSION['token'] = rand(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['token'] ?>">
```

Então, na página de pesquisa:

```
<?php if($_GET['token'] === $_SESSION['token']){} ?>
```

Novamente, depende de qual pesquisa possuí.

Parece um exemplo bizzaro? Sim, mas justamente para que perceba que seu site pode vir até o mesmo erro. Como? Imagine que quer incluir uma lista por ordem de "mais procurados", ou recompensar postagens mais procuradas, sem o tal `token` isso pode ser facilmente manipulado.

> Não consegui achar nenhum site para citar um exemplo real, desprotegido, se achar volto a editar!

Uma outra coisa é permitir que outras pessoas saibam se o usuário está ou não conectado através de qualquer link, incluindo ou não o seu campo de pesquisa, caso ele exiba ou possua parâmetro especifico para um usuário conectado.

Por exemplo o Google, é possível saber se você está ou não logado usando o link:

```js
function logado(){
    alert('Você está CONECTADO no Google');
}

function deslogado(){
   alert('Você está DESconectado do Google :(');
}
```

```html
<img style="display: none;" onError='deslogado()' onLoad="logado()" alt="" src="https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?continue=https://www.google.com/intl/en/images/logos/accounts_logo.png" />
```

> Experimente acessar este post numa janela anônima para ver a magia ocorrer. :)

O mesmo processo pode ocorrer com a tag `script` em seu caso, por exemplo.

A correção disso é complicada, tanto que até o próprio Google está com tal problema, o Twitter tinha algo similar e foi corrigido. A saída do Twitter foi tirar todas as imagens e JS/CSS fora do domínio twitter.com, criando um outro site/subdomínio para isso. Dessa forma o `https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=`, link responsável por redirecionar o usuário automaticamente se estiver conectado, não funciona para arquivos externos ao twitter.com. Este próprio link apenas permite que o `redirect_after_login` não contenha o `http://img.twitter.com`, por exemplo.

No Google não existe esse tratamento. O que fez com que seja possível incluir um logo do Google Accounts fora do link do `accounts.google.com`. O `CheckCookie` retorna erro se o usuário não estiver conectado, então tudo funciona.

> **Não fique preso aos exemplos citados!**

Comment: Inkeliz, entendi boa parte do que vc falou, porém fiquei um pouco sem entender parte da "saída nesse caso", poderia reforçar essa parte?

Comment: Depende de cada caso e se vale o esforço para isso. No caso "código aleatório" você precisa criar um Token. Esse token será verificado sempre com a sessão atual. Existem artigos mais elaborados em https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet, para entender de fato. A ideia é que outro site não seja capaz de executar a ação ao invés do usuário. Como o token impede isso? Simples, o site não conseguirá obter o "token" (código aleatório) válido, portanto sem token nada é feito. É logico que `rand()` é  pouco, mas é um exemplo. Irei editar em breve.

Comment: Adicionei outros exemplos que conseguir pensar, mas todos eles não expõe de fato seu código ou comprometem (diretamente) o seu site. Até espero que outros usuários venham a inserir problemas que realmente afetem o "sistema do site" diretamente.

Comment: Eu poderia dizer que é assim que sites como o zoom, acessam e comparam os preços de diversos produtos?

Comment: Sim e não. Talvez quando iniciaram o site eles utilizaram essas "APIs" ocultas. Mas...  Muitos sites de lojas possuem API para anunciantes, ou seja uma API própria, especifica para essa finalidade. Mas, quando você é um site pequeno (ou está com medo de investir) poderá usar esses "problemas" para monitorar os preços dos produtos e mantê-lo atualizado facilmente. Uma alternativa é usar a Buscapé, eles tem uma API para isso. Porém eu acho, pessoalmente, muito desatualizada, melhor ir fuçando o próprio site do vendedor diretamente, depois entrar em contato com eles para algo "oficial".